# AuthorizeRoles=admin how redirect to index when is false.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

In my **MVC 4** application with `SimpleMembershipProvider`. I'm decorating my controller with attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`.

When Roles is false I'm redirecting user to **Login** page. How can I change it to redirect to **Index** page?

Comment: If you redirect to the home page instead of the login page then your users will lose the ability to get back in your system?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom authorize attribute by overriding `AuthorizeAttribute` as

```
 [CustomAuthAttribute(Roles = "Admin")]
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;

public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
           /* if authorization condition fails */
           if(!condition)
           {
              HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
           }
        }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                        {
                            { "action", "/*ActionName*/" },
                            { "controller", "/*ControllerName*/" }
                        });
   }
}
```